# Mudar valor do padrão americano para padrão brasileiro no Java Script

Tags: javascript, replace

Nesse código é solicitado que digite um número numa window.prompt.
Usei o replace para poder aceitar o padrão brasileiro com vírgula.

Minha dúvida é, como eu faço para ele converter para vírgula novamente quando for exibir o resultado da soma?

> Exemplo:
> A soma entre 3 e 3,5 é 6,5
> quero que exiba assim com vírgula e não ponto.

```js
var PrimeiroNúmero = window.prompt('Digite um número: ')
var SegundoNúmero = window.prompt('Digite outro número: ')
var n1 = parseFloat(PrimeiroNúmero.replace(',', '.'))
var n2 = parseFloat(SegundoNúmero.replace(',', '.'))
var soma = n1 + n2
window.alert(`A soma entre  ${n1} e ${n2} é ${soma}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução simples e portável, da mesma forma que fez na pergunta use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para a partir da string representando o resultado obtida com [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) para substituir o ponto decimal por vírgula:

```js
const primeiro = "3";
const segundo = "3,5";
const n1 = parseFloat(primeiro.replace(',', '.'));
const n2 = parseFloat(segundo.replace(',', '.'));
const soma = n1 + n2;

const resultado = soma.toString().replace('.', ',');     //Converte soma em String e usa o mesmo artificio usado na pergunta.

console.log(`A soma entre ${primeiro} e ${segundo} é ${resultado}`);
```

> **Aviso:**
> Quanto ao Node.js o código abaixo só funcionará adequadamente caso o
> servidor esteja configurado com suporte a internacionalização adequado a linguagem.

Outra solução caso o seu código seja executado apenas em navegadores outra solução é utilizar o método [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) que retorna uma string com uma representação de um número sensível a língua e cultura especificada, no caso por português brasileiro.

```js
const primeiro = "3";
const segundo = "3,5";
const n1 = parseFloat(primeiro.replace(',', '.'));
const n2 = parseFloat(segundo.replace(',', '.'));
const soma = n1 + n2;

const resultado = soma.toLocaleString("pt-BR");     //Converte soma em String segundo a cultura pt-BR.

console.log(`A soma entre ${primeiro} e ${segundo} é ${resultado}`);
```

Outra alternativa que pode ser utilizada em [navegadores modernos](https://caniuse.com/?search=formatToParts) e o Node.js, sem o suporte a internacionalização específico, é personalizar a formatação usando o método [`Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) da [API de Internacionalização.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl). Veja o exemplo:

```js
const n = 35.81;
const f = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
console.log(f.formatToParts(n));
/*[
 {"type": "integer", "value": "35"},
 {"type": "decimal", "value": "." },
 {"type": "fraction", "value": "81"}
]*/
```

O método `formatToParts()` é usado para formatação personalizada de strings numéricas pois retorna um Array de objetos contendo os componentes específicos da localidade a partir dos quais é possível construir strings personalizadas enquanto preserva as partes específicas da localidade.

Para solucionar o problema algoritmo é simples:

- Crie um objeto de formatação numérica na localidade local com [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat).
- Quebre a representação numérica em um [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de suas componentes com `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts()`.
- Varra com [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as componentes e as personalize.No caso caso foi personalizado a componente cujo `type == "decimal"` que define a  string separadora decimal `"."`.
- Reconstrua a representação numérica a partir das componentes personalizadas usando [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const primeiro = "3";
const segundo = "3,5";
const n1 = parseFloat(primeiro.replace(',', '.'));
const n2 = parseFloat(segundo.replace(',', '.'));
const soma = n1 + n2;

const formatador = new Intl.NumberFormat();                //Cria um objeto de formatação numérica da localidade local(default).
const resultado = formatador.formatToParts(soma)           //Quebra a representação numérica em suas componentes.
 .map(({type, value}) => (type == "decimal")? "," : value) //Varre as componentes e caso type == "decimal" substitui o seu valor por virgula mantendo as outras componentes inalteradas.
 .reduce((str, part) => str + part);                       //Reconstrói a representação numérica.

console.log(`A soma entre ${primeiro} e ${segundo} é ${resultado}`);
```